# Why 'acquire/release' can not guarantee sequential consistency in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic, happens-before

```
-Thread 1-                
y.store (20, memory_order_release); 
x.store (10, memory_order_release);

-Thread 2-
if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10) {
  assert (y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 20);
  y.store (10, memory_order_release)
}

-Thread 3-
if (y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10) {
  assert (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10);
}
```

[GCC Atomic Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) paragraph “Overall Summary” says， the above code `assert(x.load(memory_order_acquire))` can **fail**. But I don't understand why ?

My understanding is：

1. Thread3 can not **LoadLoad** reorder due to **acquire** barrier.
2. Thread1 can not **StoreStore** reorder due to **release** barrier.
3. When Thread2 read(x)->10, x must be flushed from storebuffer to cache in Thread1, so every thread know the value x has changed, such as invalidate cache line.
4. Thread3 uses **Acquire** barrier, so it can see x(10).

Comment: "*I don't understand why*" Unless the Wiki article changed in the last hour (and while I'm not good at navigating their backwards Wiki system, I don't see it under RecentChanges), what you posted is *not the same code* as the example. So that's the reason why you're confused. The example on that page always uses `relaxed`; it never uses `acquire/release`.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is, under 'Overall Summary', and then the 'release/acquire mode' sub-section

Comment: @LWimsey: No, it's not. "Overall Summary" has some code that uses `memory_order_relaxed` and `memory_order_seq_cst` as the first two atomic operations. And the "release/acquire mode" section has no example matching *that* code. It has something that looks like part of that code, but not the full code. And the section specifically says that the assert won't fire. Just search for "y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10"; you *will not* find it on that page.

Comment: The release/acquire sub-section implies that all stores are release operations and all loads are acquire operations

Comment: @LWimsey: ... I'm not sure I understand how that applies to what I'm saying. The OP has posted code, then claims that the GCC wiki says that this code does not work. The GCC wiki ***says no such thing***. It does not provide that code. It does not say that the given code does not work. The question is invalid.

Comment: @NicolBolas Again, if you read the 'Overall Summary' section, it literally says in the first line: _**examine this case for each of the different memory models**_.. And then they show the code without ordering parameters. For the Acq/Rel case, that gives exactly the code as shows by the OP.

Comment: @NicolBolas GCC wiki: Release/acquire mode only requires the two threads involved to be synchronized. This means that synchronized values are not commutative to other threads. The assert in thread 2 must still be true since thread 1 and 2 synchronize with x.load(). Thread 3 is not involved in this synchronization, so when thread 2 and 3 synchronize with y.load(), thread 3's assert can fail. There has been no synchronization between threads 1 and 3, so no value can be assumed for 'x' there.

Comment: @Pengcheng "_synchronized values are not commutative to other threads_" commutative?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad example, though it does illustrate how mind-warping relaxed atomics can be, I suppose.

[intro.execution]p9:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a
>   full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

[atomics.order]p2:

> An atomic operation *A* that performs a release operation on an atomic
>   object *M* synchronizes with an atomic operation *B* that performs an
>   acquire operation on *M* and takes its value from any side effect in the
>   release sequence headed by *A*.

As a result, the evaluations shown are chained together by sequenced-before and synchronized-with relationships:

```
Thread 1                   Thread 2              Thread 3

y.store(20)
   |
   | s.b.
   V           s.w.
x.store(10)  -------->  x.load() == 10
                               |
                               | s.b.
                               V      s.w.
                        y.store(10) --------> y.load() == 10
                                                  |
                                                  | s.b.
                                                  V
                                              x.load() == ?
```

And so each evaluation in the chain *happens before* the next (see [intro.races]p9-10).

[intro.races]p15,

> If a value computation *A* of an atomic object *M* happens before a value
>   computation *B* of *M*, and *A* takes its value from a side effect *X* on *M*,
>   then the value computed by *B* shall either be the value stored by *X* or
>   the value stored by a side effect *Y* on *M*, where *Y* follows *X* in the
>   modification order of *M*.

Here, *A* is the load in Thread 2 that took the value 10, *B* is the load in Thread 3 (in the assert). Since *A* happens before *B*, and there are no other side effects on `x`, *B* must also read 10.

---

Herb Sutter has a much simpler example [on his blog](https://herbsutter.com/2013/10/28/reader-qa-acquirerelease-and-sequential-consistency/):

```
T1: x = 1;
T2: y = 1;
T3: if( x == 1 && y == 0 ) puts("x first");
T4: if( y == 1 && x == 0 ) puts("y first");
```

You absolutely need sequential consistency to guarantee that at most one line is printed.

Comment: I think the gcc Wiki people do have a point..
The happens-before relationship that is established between thread 1 and 2 applies to operations sequenced before the release (on `x`) in thread 1 and operations sequenced after the acquire in thread 2.
Technically, the `x` variable is not part of this "sequenced before/after" and they may not be wrong that it can become visible out-of-order in thread 3.

Comment: @LWimsey I think it is safe to say, huh? The answer _proved_ `x` must read `10`

Comment: @LWimsey If they purport to implement the C++11 memory model, then they are dead wrong.

Comment: @T.C. I agree, The compelling argument is that the two loads from x are ordered

Comment: @LWimsey A stronger argument to be made about the std is by disregarding the whole std text (which is very often complete garbage) and assuming something else (that is usable) was written instead. If you can't assume that acquiring in Ta (observing) a released (published) history by another thread Tb doesn't also put in the past of Ta the observations of Tb including the past of other threads Tx that Tb has put in his past by acquiring a released state, then acquiring in a mutex would be practically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is special case of multithread program that only use atomic objects for synchronization, not for communicating information with significant entropy: **the only values written act as milestones**.

It means that any store:

- is a release operation
- communicates a value that indicate a precise point in the progress of one thread

The form must be exactly `A.store (C, memory_order_release);`
where:

- `A` is an atomic object
- `C` is a constant

and the pair `(A,C)` characterizes uniquely the program line.

And conversely each load:

- is an acquire
- only checks for a particular value

The form must be exactly

```
if (A.load(memory_order_acquire) == C) { ... }
```

where there is no else clause.

Reading a particular value indicates progress and establish that all previous side effect (before a particular program point) have happened. That small class of programs never has funny multithread behavior because everything is a function of progress: milestones are passed, and the behavior must be purely sequential.